# How to grant lambda permission to upload file to s3 bucket in `terraform`?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

I have below lambda function configuration in `TerraForm`:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  # filename         = "crawler/dist/deploy.zip"
  s3_bucket = "${var.s3-bucket}"
  s3_key    = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.file_upload.key}"
  # source_code_hash = "${filebase64sha256("file.zip")}"
  function_name    = "quote-crawler"
  role             = "arn:aws:iam::773592622512:role/LambdaRole"
  handler          = "handler.handler"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.zipit.output_base64sha256}"
  runtime          = "${var.runtime}"
  timeout          = 180

  environment {
    variables = {
      foo = "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

when I run the lambda I got the error `"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied",` when it tries to upload file to s3 bucket. It seems that the lambda function doesn't have permission to access s3. `TerraForm` doc is not clear about how to configure them. The permission configuration panel doesn't appear on `lambda console` either. It seems that lambda that created by `TerraForm` has limited configuration for me to use. So how can I grant s3 permission to lambda?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make it easy you can do this in three steps,

1. create a role
2. create policy
3. attached policy to the role
4. attached role to lambda

Create role.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
  name = "${var.env_prefix_name}-alb-logs-to-elk"
  path = "/"

      assume_role_policy = <<EOF
    {

  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Create a policy that has specified access to s3

```
 #Created Policy for IAM Role
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name = "${var.env_prefix_name}-test-policy"
  description = "A test policy"


      policy = <<EOF
   {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
]

} 
    EOF
    }
```

Attached IAM Role and the new created Policy

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.policy.arn}"
}
```

Now attached the role to Lamba source

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  # filename         = "crawler/dist/deploy.zip"
  s3_bucket = "${var.s3-bucket}"
  s3_key    = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.file_upload.key}"
  # source_code_hash = "${filebase64sha256("file.zip")}"
  function_name    = "quote-crawler"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.role.arn}"
  handler          = "handler.handler"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.zipit.output_base64sha256}"
  runtime          = "${var.runtime}"
  timeout          = 180

  environment {
    variables = {
      foo = "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The IAM role associated to the function is not allowed to upload to S3.

The solution is to create an IAM policy allowing S3 access to your bucket (say read/write), which would look something like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, you need to attach this policy to the role used by your lambda function.

More info at:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy.html

Answer (score 3):

I would do it in the following order:

> this code is using terraform 0.12.*

1. Create policy documents for assume role and s3 permissions

```
data aws_iam_policy_document lambda_assume_role {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

data aws_iam_policy_document lambda_s3 {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:PutObjectAcl"
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

2. Create an IAM policy

```
resource aws_iam_policy lambda_s3 {
  name        = "lambda-s3-permissions"
  description = "Contains S3 put permission for lambda"
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda_s3.json
}
```

3. Create a role

```
resource aws_iam_role lambda_role {
  name               = "lambda-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda_assume_role.json
}
```

4. Attach policy to role

```
resource aws_iam_role_policy_attachment lambda_s3 {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_s3.arn
}
```

5. Attach role to lambda

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  # filename         = "crawler/dist/deploy.zip"
  s3_bucket = var.s3-bucket
  s3_key    = aws_s3_bucket_object.file_upload.key
  # source_code_hash = "${filebase64sha256("file.zip")}"
  function_name    = "quote-crawler"
  role             = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  handler          = "handler.handler"
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.zipit.output_base64sha256
  runtime          = var.runtime
  timeout          = 180

  environment {
    variables = {
      foo = "bar"
    }
  }
}
```